# Rotation of a character around another character centered

Tags: math-mode, symbols, rotating, text

Suppose you have a character in the center, how should you rotate another character near it clockwise or counterclockwise?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean... is the picture the intended output? Then you need no rotation at all.

Comment: @campa I wrote rotation but I would like one letter to revolve around another. Yes I have drawing the output.

Comment: So something like `\begin{tabular}{ccc}&B\\B&A&B\\&B\end{tabular}` (apart from spacing)?

Comment: @campa yes but is there only this solution?

Comment: Of course you may concoct a dozen different solutions. What's wrong with this one? I am starting to sense an XY problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a macro `\revolve` that takes 3 arguments, one optional:

`\revolve[<optional formatting>]{<center symbol>}{<revolve symbol>}`

You can adjust the vertical spacing by changing `-.5ex` (twice), and horizontal spacing by changing `\,` (twice).

[image]

A few examples are given in the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\revolve}[3][]{{#1\begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c}&#3\\[-.5ex]#3&#2&#3\\[-.5ex]&#3\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\revolve{A}{B}\quad
\revolve{\textsf{A}}{\textsf{B}}\quad
\revolve[\color{blue}]{A}{B}\quad
\revolve[\Large\sffamily\bfseries]{\color{red}A}{\color{green!60!black}B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.

Answer (score 5):

The macro `\revolve` using TeX primitives only:

```
\def\revolve#1#2{\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr#2\cr#2 #1 #2\cr#2\cr}}}
% test:
\revolve AB
```

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu